# Reading binary file multiple choice Java

Tags: java, binary

I'm solving old exams multiple choice questions and I'm having this one which troubles me:

Which class would you choose to read from a binary file:

a. FileReader
b.BufferedReader
c.DataOutputStream
d.ObjectInputStream

I dont think that any of this is correct. For binary files we have FileInputStream. What's going on wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer should be **ObjectInputStream**

FileInputStream:
FileInputStream is used to open file to read.

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("welcome");
```

It checks wheither the file exist or not if file exist opens the file for reading otherwise FileNotFoundException will thrown.

ObjectInputStream:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("welcome");
ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
```

It opens the file for reading object.